# Empty Class Definition Trap?

Tags: css, class, optimization

Every once in a while I define an empty CSS class such as

```
.empty{}
```

to enable me to manipulate a whole sequence of DOM elements easily in jQuery.  From what I have seen thus far all the major browsers allow me to get away with this.  However, I was wondering... are there any W3C guidelines that might mean that one day browsers strip out/ignore such empty class declarations?  I have scanned the, oh so dry, W3C documentation but have not been able to find anything terribly relevant on the subject.

Comment: "I define an empty CSS class... to enable me to manipulate a whole sequence of DOM elements easily in jQuery" How does that work?

Comment: Why do you need to define that CSS in the first place? It does nothing relevant to jQuery.

Comment: What I do from time-to-time is something along the lines of $.each($('.myemptyclass'),function(ndx,elem){...})

Comment: then you don't need to declare it in CSS...

Comment: @DroidOS: Why do you think that needs a corresponding CSS declaration? Just for the selector?

Comment: The question is based on a misunderstanding. There are no “CSS classes”. Classes are defined by the HTML `class` attribute (or corresponding JavaScript operations on the DOM). CSS may make use of them like anyone else. The jQuery notation `.empty` has the same format as a CSS selector, but it does not need any CSS definition or declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you just use this class as a hook to get the desired elements via jQuery.
Nothing wrong with that, will work forever (or till the zombie apocalypse).

Browsers will never start and just *remove* any elements which are completely valid.

I am pretty gutsy in saying "never" :-D

But there is no need for a CSS-declaration for that class which has no properties at all.
But it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason for using this goes something like this: Suppose you have n elements which all use the same class(es) and you have a need to manipulate a subset m of those n elements via jQuery.  I stick in an empty class declaration into the mix of classes to do the job.  Like I said, it works ... and will do until some smarty pants browser decides that the empty class declaration is useless (which it is to all but I) and strips it out. I have never seen this happening so I was wondering... might it happen one day?

Comment: @DroidOS: What makes you think you need a CSS rule for something that is part of the HTML DOM?

Comment: Ummm...  I am sticking in the CSS rule into the m subset (see comment above) so I can quickly get to it via jQuery.  It sounds like you are suggesting that there is a smarter way of getting at that m subset quickly?

Comment: Let me give a more concrete example.  I have a jQuery Mobile page with, say, 4 popups containng iframes.  3 of those four popups contain a map, the fourth one contains a video.  I need to manipulate the iframes inside the popups in order to ensure that they work in all browsers - see here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html. Only, the manipulations are different for map popups and video popups...

Comment: This will work perfectly well the way you did it. And will work so in the future.
But, as mentioned several times, your CSS-rule is absolutely useless.
Browsers won't drop it, but you could. And it wouldn't change anything.
As long as the class attribute in your HTML has this class, you can filter for it via Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use class names as you like in your jQuery code. jQuery does not mandate a corresponding style definition for each class name you use in the code.

For ex: if you are using a class named `selected` to identify all selected elements, you need not have a `.selected {}` definition in your css.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you quite understood (my fault, I am sure) what I was driving at.  See what user1207449 says below.

Comment: The thing is since your class definition is empty, it does not really matter even if one day browsers decide to strip it off. What matters is that jQuery does not care if a style definition for a particular class exists or not. Your JS code that uses non existent classes will continue to work correctly.